# How to scroll content?

Tags: android, textview, android-button, android-scrollview

I have the following problem:

I need 18 Button with a `TextView` beside them and one `TextView` on the top among themselves. Of course, they don't fit on the display and so I searched this problem and find the `ListView` but this doesn't work for me because I need 18 `Buttons` and `TextViews` with different Ids.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: will u more elaborate what u need ???

Comment: Why do you need different ids for each of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**use**     `<ScrollView>` **Note**     `<ScrollView>` **has only one direct child**

**so it must used like**  **:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <!--  your contents  are here  -->
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```